# What is a sharp constant?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I've been reading some papers and found this term "Sharp constant" being used in inequalities frequently. Can anyone provide me a detailed meaning of this term ? I couldn't find proper resources to learn about this.

For example, statements are along the following lines:

$
f(x) \leq C g(x) , x \in \mathbb{R}
$
where C is a sharp constant.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The term sharp means we can find a best bound,  that cannot be improved by a better number.   I.e.,  to say a function is bounded is to say there exists an $M$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$.  To say a particular number is sharp, say $|f(x)|\le 3$, means that there is no number smaller than 3 we could put there and have it be true.

Comment: In a sense, its like the supremum or infimum for our expressions right ?

Comment: Pretty much so, yes.   Generally in math, first some bound is found, and then the goal is to find a sharp bound,  i.e. the sup/inf/best.

Comment: no problem.  If this answered your question, you should click the check mark to accept it :)